# java serialization and inheritance

Tags: java, serialization

In 2 java classes , If class A implements Serializable and class B extends A, then by default is Class B Serializable also? From what I understand, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  This follows from the concept of inheritance in Java.  Since A is serializable and B extends A, B is serializalbe.  Worth noting, notice that B is not "Default" Serializable, there is no choice as long as B extends A.

Comment: I don't know what your last sentence means.

Comment: This means that if you extend class B, A will always be considered Serializable.

Comment: You already said that in your scond sentence. The last sentence just confuses things. I would delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct. However, note that all fields of A and B must also contain Serializable objects, otherwise there will be a `NotSerializableException` at runtime when you try to serialize them.